# EmberJs using inject.controller to access parent data

Tags: ember.js

I am trying to access from a child template to its parent data
in the previous versions of emberjs this could have be done using the needs keyword:

```
app.RepositoriesController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    needs: "user",
    user : Ember.computed.alias("controllers.user");
 });
```

from what I understand with the new ember version this should be done like the following (as the needs keywords became deprecated):

```
app.RepositoriesController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    user: Ember.inject.controller('user')
});
```

but it doesn't seems to work in my html code I use the following line which is blank:

```
{{user.name}}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you need to do is call:

```
user: Ember.inject.controller()
```

And ember is smart enough to automatically pick up the correct controller based on the property key.

http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.inject.html#method_controller

Comment: how do you do this in octane?

Comment: Old post but here's one note. If you call user controller's methods, those methods cannot access user's variables. To set user variables it haveto be done from caller. Classic style like this: this.set('user.variable', value);

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that it is the best practice but it did the job:
i added into the Route a new function :

```
setupController: function (controller, model) {
    var user = this.modelFor('user');
    controller.set('user', user);
    Ember.$.getJSON(user.repos_url).then(function(res){
        controller.set('model', res);
    });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

usually fetching data should go to model hook so your code above could be written as:

```
model: function(){
 var user = this.modelFor('user');
 return Ember.$.getJSON(user.repos_url).then(function(res){
   return { user: user, res: res}
 });
}
```

in controller now you can access model like

```
 user: Ember.computed.alias('model.user'),
 res: Ember.computed.alias('model.res')
```